# Using condition in list comprehension in haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

I want to use list comprehension to print only true

```
listTo::(a->b)->[a]->[b]
listTo f list=[f(x)|x<-list,x==True]

isTrue::Int->Bool
isTrue n
    |n>=5 =True
    |n<5 =False


listTo isTrue[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

But this doesn't work. Why is it?

Comment: you are comparing x (type a) with True (Bool)

Comment: For future reference, questions are a lot easier to answer when "this doesn't work" is given more detail. Does it fail to compile (if so, what is the error message)? Does it produce the wrong result? What result are you expecting to get if it did work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[f(x)|x<-list,x==True]
```

This says "give me a list of `f x`<sup>1</sup>, where `x` comes from `list` and `x` is equal to `True`.

But for your case, you've passed `list` as a list of numbers. And it looks like you want to only include those numbers for which `f x` returns `True`. So rather than comparing `x` against `True` and emitting `f x`, you should be doing the opposite. Something more like:

```
[x | x <- list, f x == True]
```

But we can improve this a little further. `==` is a function which takes two arguments and returns `True` if they're equal and `False` if they're not. So `f x == True` is going to return `True` if `f x` is `True`, and `False` if `f x` is `False`. Seems like a waste of effort; you could just write `f x`!

```
[x | x <- list, f x]
```

So that's how you use a list comprehension to do this. But as postman noted, there is already a standard library function to do exactly this: `filter`. That's what you would use if you were writing code to get things done, rather than to learn how things work.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that `f(x)` is just parsed as `f` applied to the parenthesised sub-expression `(x)`. Putting parentheses around `x` does nothing, so that's exactly equivalent to `f x`. Haskell's syntax for function application is **not** C-like `function(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, but rather `function arg1 arg2`, where the arguments are simply written out after the function (separated by whitespace if necessary). Parentheses are used *only* for controlling precedence and forming tuples. If you start trying to call functions on multiple arguments by putting parentheses around the argument list you're going to run into even more errors.

Answer (score 5):

You should really consider using `filter`, like this:

```
filter isTrue [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 3):

In `listTo`, `list` has type `[a]`. Therefore `x` has type `a`. But then you're comparing `x == True`, which means that `x` should have type `Bool` - a contradiction.

If you change the type signature to `listTo :: (Bool -> b) -> [Bool] -> [b]`, it compiles. However, you won't be able to use it with `listTo isTrue [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` as `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` is obviously not of type `[Bool]`.

It's not entirely clear to me what this code is supposed to be doing, but you should look into using `map` or `filter`.